# Jenkins as root cannot create folder

Tags: 16.04, permissions, jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance running that should build an Android project. 
When I start the task, I receive the following exception:

> Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using
>   BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()
>
> Failed to create parent directory
>   '/home/espresso/jenkins_workspace/workspace/myproject/.gradle' when
>   creating directory
>   '/home/espresso/jenkins_workspace/workspace/myproject/.gradle/4.1/fileHashes'

Jenkins runs as root, `ls -la` for `myproject` folder is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Nov 16 15:07 myproject
```

The environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` is set to `/home/espresso/.gradle`, `ls -la` for that folder gives:

```
drwxrwxrwx   6 root     root       4096 Nov 16 11:30 .gradle
```

Why can't Jenkins create that folder? The whole directory structure under `jenkins_workspace` was created by Jenkins, so the permissions should be okay?

Comment: `jenkins runs as root` what makes you sure about this?

Comment: @derHugo a. running 'whoami' in the build task prints 'root' b. the task checks out the project from Github, after checking out, all the files are owned by 'root'

Comment: Does it only happen with Jenkins? If you log in as root and run the script, does it work?

Comment: @Katu Yes, when I login as root, I can create any folders, and running the same gradle command as the script would do runs fine.

Comment: @Ascorbin Have you checked the value of GRADLE_USER_HOME within the jenkins script? Do you clean before running it? How do run the script as root? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840526/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-initscripthandler-using-buildscopeservic

Comment: @Katu Your comment brought me on the right track. thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Everything runs fine after checking the box

```
Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace
```

on the [Jenkins Gradle Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin).

Why this makes it work, I don't know. The environment variable `$GRADLE_USER_HOME` for the job was set to `/home/espresso/.gradle` and the job, as root, had all permissions for that folder. Also, I don't understand why missing permissions in one gradle folder would lead to the job not being able to create files in *another* gradle folder.